# Persisting Dynamic Controls in Excel application-level Add-in

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, vsto

I'm developing an Excel Application-level Add-In, and I want to save the Windows Forms Controls I add dynamically to the document, because by default, Excel removes all the controls after closing the document.

Here is everything explained: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442765.aspx

"Store information about the size, location, and state of the controls when the document is saved or closed. In an application-level add-in, you can save this data to a custom XML part in the document."

As it is said in the MSDN, I have to save the controls and re-create them after opening the document, but I am not able to store them in a custom XML part.

I have had a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx, but I still don't know how to do it.

Basically, I have a List of controls added to the document, and that's the object I have to save.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel sh;    
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel Worksheet vstoWorksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Sh);
//This is the List I have to save.
vstoWoorksheet.Controls
```

Thank you for your time, I hope someone can help me.